# How can I block using of YouTube app as well as YouTube website in all browsers on iPhone 5s?

Tags: ios, youtube, websites, parental-controls

My 10-year-old son is using YouTube every day for like 5-6 hours on his iPhone 5s.

Is it possible to block using YouTube app as well as accessing [www.youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com), so that he is not wasting his childhood?

If it is possible, is it possible to unblock it back for some time, when I want to let him use YouTube for 2-3 hours on Friday and Saturday and then block it again?

There is YouTube app installed on the phone and also Safari and Chrome browsers.

**What I've tried so far:**

- I've used Screen Time to block access to the YouTube website via all browsers. However, I this doesn't block the YouTube app itself.
- I have uninstalled the YouTube app from the iPhone and blocked installing of new apps via the App Store.

**Question:** 
How can I keep the YouTube app installed on his iPhone and block/unblock the app whenever I want?

Comment: Parental controls and screen time. Please see the support article https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201304

Comment: Thank you @ankiiiiiii !!!
If I block the website via Screen Time, it will not be able to access that website via any browser on iPhone, even if a new browser is installed on the phone later?

Comment: @JANORTS that Apple site should be able to answer all of your questions.  Take a look at it and then if you have any other specific questions about it, come back and [edit] your question.

Comment: @JANORTS the section under prevent web content is not browser specific. So it seems to be working at a lower level than that. so yes is my guess. you can prevent installation of new apps by PaCo. Any new app will require your permission.

Comment: @JANORTS Can you try putting a time limit on YouTube app using Screentime , or entertainment category for that matter?